# Change hyphen to comma in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this: "`PALS español K- add-on`" and I want to replace `-` with `,`. The end result should be: "`PALS español K, add-on`"

How can I do that with JavaScript?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you done *anything* or even searched up anything?

Comment: What is the hard part? Use of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, or create a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for the method?

Comment: Are you asking to only change the first occurrence of the hyphen or all cases? From your example it looks like you are asking for only the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
string="blablabla-";
String=string.replace("- ",",");
```

Syntax:

```
result=string.replace(original, replacer);
```

This takes the string and replaces the original characters found with the "replacer". I've  added a slash in my " original" ("- ") to prevent the detection of the add-on.

Comment: T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶l̶a̶c̶e̶ ̶b̶o̶t̶h̶ ̶h̶y̶p̶h̶e̶n̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶u̶l̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶'̶P̶A̶L̶S̶ ̶e̶s̶p̶a̶ñ̶o̶l̶ ̶K̶,̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶,̶o̶n̶'̶

Edit: Answer has been edited

Comment: Please look my scenario . I want  'PALS español K- add-on' to  'PALS español K, add-on'.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Say,

```
str == "PALS español K- add-o"
```

Simply use:

```
str.replace("-", ",")
```

The output is `"PALS español K, add-o"`, as desired.

---

`.replace(a, b)` simply replaces every occurrence of `a` with `b`. It can also be used to make more complicated replacements though: [MDN: .replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)